# How can F# report syntax and semantic errors at same time?

Tags: f#

Here is an F# code with both syntax and semantic errors:

```
let a b = b b
let x = (if)
```

EDIT: F# for Vim reports both the infinite type error and the syntax error, but `fsc` or `fsi` stops only at the sytnax error.

[image]

How does F# for Vim report syntax and semantic error at same time, while the F# compiler stop at only reporting syntax errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The F# compiler (which is used by the Vim plugin under the cover) has an error recovery mechanism - this means that when it finds an expression it cannot parse, it attempts to fill it with something that would make it valid F# expression.

When you write `let a = (if)`, I guess the compiler internally expands this to something like
`let a = (if _ then _ else _)` where `_` is a special "invalid expression" placeholder.

This makes it possible to type-check invalid F# code, which is really useful in the IDE when writing code (which is often invalid) because type information are used for auto-completion etc.

Reporting the type-checking errors in the automatically "fixed" code when running the compiler directly would be possible, but probably not that useful - when filling in the holes, the compiler may not always do what you expect and so this would probably give odd error messages.